# Change single result query to multiple results

Tags: mysql

I have a table called family with Parents who have multiple children, this query below returns the result for 1 Parent.

How can i change this query to return the results it does normally for a single parent for all parents ? Just like a foreach loop.

```
SELECT 
    Parent, `Children`, frequency
FROM
    family
WHERE
    Parent = 'John'
GROUP BY Parent , `Children`
ORDER BY frequency DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking then. Are you saying you want to list all the children and have it return their parent too?

Comment: A Parent has multiple children, these children have something called frequency which could be how many times they leave the house. What i want to do is get the child that leaves the house the most in each family(parent)

Comment: I see, would something like this be what you're after? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6481/5

Comment: @mituw16 it's close ! But remember i only want the top child(with highest frequency) per family that is why i had the limit.

Comment: I see, try this version of the query then. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6481/12

Comment: @mituw16 reply as answer ! Thanks works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize the `MAX()` command within MySQL

```
SELECT parent, child, MAX(frequency) from families
GROUP BY parent
ORDER BY parent, frequency desc
```

**SQL Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6481/12

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you just remove the WHERE clause? That'll iterate through everything. I also do not see any joins. So everything being in the same table.

Comment: and what happens to the LIMIT clause for each parent ?

Comment: The limit simply shrinks the maximum of duplicates to One in this case. I didn't see a valid reason to remove it. Bottom line; your question was "How can i change this query to return the results it does normally for a single parent for all parents ? Just like a foreach loop."
And this is done by simply removing your WHERE clause. it'll look like that for a 2 parents 2 children family... It's what you asked for.
Parent Children frequency

1        1         1
1        2         1
2        1         1
2        2         1
Sorry, can't really format this. Click the edit button to see the table.